# Appealing a deleted answer on a "git prune" question

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I believe a moderator deleted my answer without reading it thoroughly.

Direct link to the now deleted answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964098/1426539

Since 2011, this topic received a lot of answers, including mine.  I recently added a comment about a new gitconfig feature and it was deleted.  No previous answers addressed this, as this is a new feature.

Comment: There is a comment by the moderator explaining the rationale for the deletion. and you still have a non-deleted identical answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964090/1426539. Considering these facts, what would be the basis for your "appeal"? Please, edit your question to include your arguments, if any.

Comment: Also, please note that the _"without reading it thoroughly"_ assertion is rather unconstructive. Especially on an answer that short. It only shows that you haven't read the comment under the deleted answer, or deliberately ignored it.

Comment: Also I'd complain about you not reading the answers to that question throughly. What point does you answer add that is not already covered in the existing ones? For example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726949/remove-tracking-branches-no-longer-on-remote/68049939#68049939) covers your points.

Comment: *"I recently added a comment about a new gitconfig feature and it was deleted."* Nit pick, but comments are something entirely different (this you are reading now, is a comment). Ironically, had your "comment" been an actual *comment*, then it likely wouldn't have been deleted.

Comment: "I recently added a comment" - If your answer was deleted, and it was a comment, then the answer was properly deleted due to the fact it was a comment.  So are you complaining about your deleted answer or deleted comment?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat FWIW here is related feature request: [When there are many answers already, help me check that mine won't repeat others](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168). Guess this would be particularly useful on a question discussed here (which currently shows [50 non-deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7726949/839601))

Answer (score 24):

Your answer (which is not a *comment*) got *deleted*. Apparently, because you posted that same answer to multiple questions:

[image]

If you disagree, you can appeal this deletion by flagging your answer with a custom moderator message. Make sure you include a good reason, other than *"I disagree"*. You'll need to explain why the answer warrants undeletion.

Comment: [The other identical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77964090).